# Triangular matrix building with Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

Need to fill a triangular matrix on MATLAB with the `ndgrid` command without using loops.

$\mathbf{Example:}$
To fill a square matrix $a_{ij} = i+2j$, for $i,j = 1..10$, the code would be :

```
[I,J] = ndgrid(1:10,1:10); A = I+2.*J;
```

But I don't know how to do so if my matrix is triangular. Say, the matrix defined by :

$a_{ij} = i+2j \quad$, if $i \le  j$ and

$a_{ij} = 0 \quad\quad\quad$, if $i > j$

Comment: Is there really no such thing? I have heard people use such term, usually more informally or in context when they did not need to specify upper/lower triangular.

Answer (score 4):

Try `[I,J] = ndgrid(1:10,1:10); A = I+2.*J; A(I > J) = 0;`

The last line creates a boolean mask which is true for the indices where $i > j$, and then zeroes out those entries of $A$.